# Getting the physical location of a file inside a ZipFile for quicker deletion via Python

Tags: python, mmap, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to find a way to delete files from inside a zip without de/recompressing the archive.

The ZipFile documentation mentions -

> ZipInfo.**header_offset**
>
> ```
> Byte offset to the file header.
> ```
>
> ZipInfo.**compress_size**
>
> ```
> Size of the compressed data.
> ```

Could this be as simple as reading `compress_size` bytes starting at `header_offset`, or is there a catch?

Does this allow for deletion by gluing parts of the compressed file directly, without de/recompression, perhaps using mmap?

Comment: given that software like 7zip or winzip rebuild the archive everytime, I suppose that there's a catch. but you can give it a try (on .zip _copies_ of course!)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre does that mean those apps decompress and recompress the entire archive for deleting a file inside it?

Comment: I would say so. Give it a try.

Comment: [zipextended](https://github.com/gambl/zipextended/blob/master/zipextended/zipfileextended.py) seems to do just that. It involves getting the ZipInfo data and writing some headers as well as the compressed file itself.